# MS SQL Replace full string based on partial match

Tags: sql-server

I want to use an SQL UPDATE query to replace everything with **starts** with "http://example.com" *up to the next double quote* with "http://new-example.com". I also want to preserve any content after that double quote.

For example this:

```
ID | CONTENT
--------------
1  | Visit our <a href="http://example.com/about-us">About Us Page</a> to learn more.
2  | Read our <a href="http://example.com/terms">Terms</a> by clicking here.
```

would become:

```
ID | CONTENT
--------------
1  | Visit our <a href="http://new-example.com">About Us Page</a> to learn more.
2  | Read our <a href="http://new-example.com">Terms</a> by clicking here.
```

I'm using SQLServer 2012 for this operation.

Comment: what is the datatype and the length of CONTENT column ??

Comment: if it was varchar(max) or nvarchar(max), use Update with .WRITE (expression,@Offset,@Length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

- [PATINDEX](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to find the start of the URL,
- [CHARINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) to find the closing quote and
- [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) to replace the content.

Code:

```
UPDATE myTable
   SET content = STUFF(content, 
                       PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content),
                       CHARINDEX('"', content, PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content)) - PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content),
                       'http://new-example.com')
 WHERE PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content) > 0;
```

---

Full working example with test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (content nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('Visit our <a href="http://example.com/about-us">About Us Page</a> to learn more.');
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('Read our <a href="http://example.com/terms">Terms</a> by clicking here.');
INSERT INTO #test VALUES ('Some other text');

UPDATE #test
   SET content = STUFF(content, 
                       PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content),
                       CHARINDEX('"', content, PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content)) - PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content),
                       'http://new-example.com')
 WHERE PATINDEX('%http://example.com%"%', content) > 0;

SELECT * FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;
```

Input:

```
Visit our <a href="http://example.com/about-us">About Us Page</a> to learn more.
Read our <a href="http://example.com/terms">Terms</a> by clicking here.
Some other text
```

Output:

```
Visit our <a href="http://new-example.com">About Us Page</a> to learn more.
Read our <a href="http://new-example.com">Terms</a> by clicking here.
Some other text
```

Improvement suggestion:

- If it bothers you that the same PATINDEX expression is repeated four times (it would bother me), wrap it in a CTE and join the CTE in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: awesome, i was typing an answer via using Update WRITE (expression,@Offset,@Length), but i was stuck with getting the accurate length. happy code.

Comment: Great I like that, +1

Answer (score 2):

You might solve this on XML base:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, CONTENT VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'Visit our <a href="http://example.com/about-us">About Us Page</a> to learn more.')
,(2,'Read our <a href="http://example.com/terms">Terms</a> by clicking here.');

DECLARE @ReplaceWith VARCHAR(100)='http://new-example.com';

WITH UpdateableCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,CONTENT
          ,CAST
            (
                CAST('<root>' + CONTENT + '</root>' AS XML).query
                (N'
                    <r>
                    {(root/text())[1]}
                    <a href="{sql:variable("@ReplaceWith")}">
                    {(/root/a/text())[1]}
                    </a>
                    {(root/text())[2]}
                    </r>
                ') AS varchar(MAX)
            ) AS NewContent
    FROM @tbl
)
UPDATE UpdateableCTE SET CONTENT=SUBSTRING(NewContent,4,LEN(NewContent)-7);

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Short explanation:
Adding a `<root>` at the beginning and a `</root>` to the end transforms your snippets to valid XML. The XML-method `.query` allows the usage of `FLWOR`-code. The given example starts with a root node `<r>`, reads the first `text()`, then adds the `<a>`-element with the `href` attribute, which is filled with the value of the sql:variable. Then there is the `text()` within `<a>`, the closing `</a>` and the second text of the root node.

The returned XML is casted to `VARCHAR` and `SUBSTRING` is used to cut away the `<r>...</r>`.